# Index out of range for multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm getting the error that the index for my array is out of range.
I define a 3D array like this:

```
Button[, ,] posAr_ItemManager = new Button[maxRows, maxColumns, maxCategories];
```

Where maxRows, maxColumns and maxCategories are all constant integers.
I then want to loop through this whole array, i do it using nested loops as shown here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(2); z++)
                {
                    if (posAr_ItemManager[i,j,z] != null)
                    {
                        Button but = posAr_ItemManager[i, j, z];
                        but.Width = itemWidth;
                        but.Height = itemHeight;
                        but.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, itemPanelX + (i + 1) * butSpacing + i * itemWidth);
                        but.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, itemPanelY + (i+1)*butSpacing + i* itemHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run the program it gives the out of range error where I check if the item is not equal to null.

I have no idea why it does it as I thought my declaration of the 3D array is correct and the nested loop as well? thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrong condition: `for (int j = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(1); j++)` change `i <` into `j <`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(2); z++)
```

look very carefully at the middle tests. Also, consider hoisting the `GetLength` tests so you only do them once per dimension. Perhaps:

```cs
int rows = posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(0), columns = posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(1),
    categories = posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(2);

for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
    {
        for (int cat = 0; cat < categories; cat++)
```

Comment: ahhhh waaauw i feel stupid now... i looked for a mistake for like 20 minutes now and i didnt notice that.. rookie mistake, thanks guys!

Comment: @cooldanietje easily done; heck, one of my colleagues just yesterday... https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1203793738629292032

Answer (score 2):

You're using "**i**" to check if the loop is over in each of the dimensions. Change it to corresponded i,j,z.

```
for (int i = 0; i < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; **j** < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; **z** < posAr_ItemManager.GetLength(2); z++)
```